# Best practices configuring ehCache in modular java application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, configuration, ehcache

We would like to use ehcache in the following two scenarios:

> - Hibernate second level cache
> - Spring method cache

Since we have a persistence.xml file in each module but only need one persistence unit, we are using org.springframework.data.jpa.support.MergingPersistenceUnitManager.

Now we would like to have a similar setup for ehcache:

> - each module has a ehcache.xml file
> - ehcache.xml files are merged together

I didn't find a solution exactly for this. There is of course another solution:

> - 1 ehcache.xml file for whole java application

Are there any other solution or best practices how we could setup ehcache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ehcache maps one configuration file to one `CacheManager`, so if you can configure your application to use one `CacheManager` per module, it will work.
There is otherwise no option to merge multiple xml configuration files into a single `CacheManager`.

Comment: So for Spring's method cache we could define separate CacheManagers per module, but not for hibernate, if there is only one persistence unit?